# Given a day of the year, how would I convert it into date/month format?

Tags: c

So basically I'm reading information from a file and storing it into multiple arrays, one of the questions being asked is to take a specific day of a year and change that into date time format. So if it's the 30th day of the year, I should output ".... 30th day of the month January", or anything that specifies the day and month.

I've been looking into strftime but I'm not too familiar with structures as of yet as I'm still learning it a bit and this is what my attempt looks like so far:

```
char time_supHi[100];
struct tm *timeHi;
time_t sup;

timeHi = localtime(&mytime);

sup = time(day[high_pos_sup]);
strftime(time_supHi, 100, "%B", mytime);
```

I have %B as a placeholder for now just to see if the right month is outputted.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't show definitions of `mytime`, `day` or `high_pos_sup` which we shouldn't have to guess. Note that it is permissible to pass a null pointer to `time()` — it doesn't try to write to that address. Passing `mytime` to `strftime()` is weird; it expects a `struct tm *` (like `sup`) and not a `time_t` value (like `mytime` should be if you pass its address to `time()`). Use `sizeof(time_supHi)` rather than `100` for the second argument to `strftime()` — always look askance at the code if you can't provide `sizeof()` for the size (but if the array is passed as a parameter, pass its size too).

Comment: I didn't notice all the declaration problems, my bad. So &mytime was actually supposed to be &timeHi which I should have fixed and is my bad and  high_pos_sup is the index of array day, which is also the day that I'm using. Just as another question, do you know if there is any easier way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If you want to convert "year (1..9999) and day of year (1..366)" to "year (1..9999), month (1..12 — or 0..11), and day (1..31)", you probably need a leap year function, and a table of number of days in each month, and then brute force the calculation.  This wouldn't touch `strftime()`, `localtime()`, or `time()`.  Taking the year, month, day information and formatting it, you probably would use `mktime()` and `strftime()` — initializing a local `struct tm` with the appropriate information (time fields zero) and then calling `mktime()` and then `strftime()`.

Comment: Ordinals (30th rather than 30) are messy — they aren't supported as standard by `strftime()`.  It's easy enough to manufacture ordinals in English; I'm not sure whether you need to worry about I18N/L10N and other languages than English.  Of course, "Nth day of the month January" is inherently antagonistic to I18N/L10N.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Stress-test `mktime()`

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static void yd_to_ymd(int year, int day);

int main(void)
{
    yd_to_ymd(1996, 300);
    putchar('\n');
    yd_to_ymd(1997, 300);
    return 0;
}

static char *fmt_ordinal(char *buffer, size_t buflen, unsigned n);
static void dump_tm(const char *tag, const struct tm *t);

static void yd_to_ymd(int year, int day)
{
    struct tm t0 =
    {
        .tm_year = year - 1900, .tm_mday = day, .tm_mon = 0,
        .tm_hour = 0, .tm_min = 0, .tm_sec = 0,
        .tm_isdst = -1,
    };

    dump_tm("t0", &t0);

    time_t uts = mktime(&t0);

    printf("%ju\n", (intmax_t)uts);
    dump_tm("t1", &t0);

    char ordinal[8];
    fmt_ordinal(ordinal, sizeof(ordinal), t0.tm_mday);
    char month[16];
    strftime(month, sizeof(month), "%B", &t0);
    char weekday[10];
    strftime(weekday, sizeof(weekday), "%A", &t0);
    printf("%s the %s day of the month of %s\n", weekday, ordinal, month);
}

static void dump_tm(const char *tag, const struct tm *t)
{
    printf("%s: %.4d-%.2d-%.2d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d (W %d; Y %3d; DST %d)\n",
           tag, t->tm_year + 1900, t->tm_mon + 1, t->tm_mday,
           t->tm_hour, t->tm_min, t->tm_sec,
           t->tm_wday, t->tm_yday + 1, t->tm_isdst);
}

static const char *const suffixes[4] = { "th", "st", "nd", "rd" };

static inline unsigned suffix_index(unsigned n)
{
    unsigned x;

    x = n % 100;
    if (x == 11 || x == 12 || x == 13)
        x = 0;
    else if ((x = x % 10) > 3)
        x = 0;
    return x;
}

static char *fmt_ordinal(char *buffer, size_t buflen, unsigned n)
{
    unsigned x = suffix_index(n);
    int len = snprintf(buffer, buflen, "%d%s", n, suffixes[x]);
    if (len <= 0 || (size_t)len >= buflen)
        return 0;
    return(buffer);
}
```

The `mktime()` function normalizes the date/time information in the `tm_year`, `tm_mon`, `tm_mday`, `tm_hour`, `tm_min`, `tm_sec` fields, using `tm_isdst` to guide choices related to Winter vs Summer time — or Daylight Saving vs Standard time. It also updates the `tm_yday` and `tm_wday` fields to reflect what's deduced.  So, by setting the structure up to describe the day of the year (e.g. 300) as the 300th day of January, `mktime()` will convert that to the correct date — 26th October in a leap year such as 1996, 27th October in a non-leap year such as 1997.

The code above initializes a `struct tm` value with the correct encoding for the 300th day of January in the given year (1996 in this example). It dumps that information via the `dump_tm()` function.  Note that this 'undoes' the encodings in the structure — it reports the value `tm_year + 1900`; it reports the value `tm_mon + 1` (so months are numbered 1..12 instead of 0..11), and it reports the value `tm_yday + 1` so 1st January is day 1 of the year rather than day 0.  It then calls the `mktime()` routine to get the Unix timestamp (seconds since the Unix Epoch — which is 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z), and calls `dump_tm()` to show the adjusted values.

Example output:

```
t0: 1996-01-300 00:00:00 (W 0; Y   1; DST -1)
846309600
t1: 1996-10-26 00:00:00 (W 6; Y 300; DST 1)
Saturday the 26th day of the month of October

t0: 1997-01-300 00:00:00 (W 0; Y   1; DST -1)
877935600
t1: 1997-10-27 00:00:00 (W 1; Y 300; DST 0)
Monday the 27th day of the month of October
```

If you look at the data from Option 2, you'll see that 1996-300 was 1996-10-26, and 1997-300 was 1997-10-27.

Given the timestamp 846309600, that corresponds to Sat Oct 26 00:00:00 1996 in the US/Mountain time zone, and 877935600 corresponds to Mon Oct 27 00:00:00 1997 (note that in 1996, the time zone was in daylight saving time, and in 1997 the time zone was in standard time — back then, the time zone did its 'fall back' on the last Sunday in October):

```
$ timestamp -l 846309600 877935600
846309600 = Sat Oct 26 00:00:00 1996
877935600 = Mon Oct 27 00:00:00 1997
$ timestamp -u 846309600 877935600
846309600 = Sat Oct 26 06:00:00 1996
877935600 = Mon Oct 27 07:00:00 1997
$ timestamp -Z -l 846309600 877935600
846309600 = Sat Oct 26 00:00:00 1996 -06:00
877935600 = Mon Oct 27 00:00:00 1997 -07:00
$ timestamp -Z -u 846309600 877935600
846309600 = Sat Oct 26 06:00:00 1996 +00:00
877935600 = Mon Oct 27 07:00:00 1997 +00:00
$ timestamp -I -Z -l 846309600 877935600
846309600 = 1996-10-26 00:00:00 -06:00
877935600 = 1997-10-27 00:00:00 -07:00
$ timestamp -I -Z -u 846309600 877935600
846309600 = 1996-10-26 06:00:00 +00:00
877935600 = 1997-10-27 07:00:00 +00:00
$
```

Or, if you prefer to use GNU `date`, then:

```
$  date -d @846309600 --iso-8601=seconds
1996-10-26T00:00:00-0600
$ date -u -d @846309600 --iso-8601=seconds
1996-10-26T06:00:00+0000
$
```

Spelling out the year or day of the month (e.g. "one thousand, nine hundred and ninety-six") is harder; the code to do that is much larger.  Making that an ordinal spelling ("… ninety-sixth") requires care too.

### Option 2: DIY

I don't think the use of `time()` or `localtime()` is warranted.  Using `strftime()` and maybe `mktime()` would be more sensible, but convert 'day of year' to 'month and day' is not standardized AFAIK.

If you want to convert "year (1..9999) and day of year (1..366)" to "year (1..9999), month (1..12), and day (1..31)", you probably need a leap year function, and a table of the number of days in each month, and then use a brute force the calculation.

#### Header `yd2ymd.c`

```
#ifndef JLSS_ID_YD2YMD_H
#define JLSS_ID_YD2YMD_H

extern int cvt_yd_to_ymd(int year, int yday, int *mon, int *day);
extern int cvt_ymd_to_yd(int year, int mon, int day, int *yday);

#endif
```

#### Source `yd2ymd.c`

```
#include "yd2ymd.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static const int days_in_month[] = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

static inline bool is_leap_year(int year)
{
    if (year % 4 != 0)
        return false;
    if (year % 100 != 0)
        return true;
    if (year % 400 == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
    /* return (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)); */
}

#define PRECOND(x) do { if (!(x)) return -1; } while (0);

int cvt_yd_to_ymd(int year, int yday, int *mon, int *day)
{
    PRECOND(year > 0 && year <= 9999);
    PRECOND(yday > 0 && (yday < 366 || (yday == 366 && is_leap_year(year))));
    assert(mon != 0 && day != 0);
    if (is_leap_year(year))
    {
        if (yday == 31 + 29)
        {
            *mon = 2;
            *day = 29;
            return 0;
        }
        if (yday > 31 + 29)
            yday--;
    }
    *mon = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        if (yday > days_in_month[i])
        {
            yday -= days_in_month[i];
            (*mon)++;
        }
        else
        {
            *day = yday;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    assert(0 || "can't happen");
    return -1;
}

int cvt_ymd_to_yd(int year, int mon, int day, int *yday)
{
    PRECOND(year > 0 && year <= 9999);
    PRECOND(mon >= 1 && mon <= 12);
    PRECOND(day >= 1 && (day <= days_in_month[mon] ||
                        (day == 29 && mon == 2 && is_leap_year(year))));
    assert(yday != 0);
    int day_num = day;
    bool leap = is_leap_year(year);
    if (day == 29 && mon == 2 && leap)
    {
            day_num += 31;
    }
    else
    {
        if (leap && mon > 2)
            day_num++;
        for (int i = 1; i < mon; i++)
            day_num += days_in_month[i];
    }
    *yday = day_num;
    return 0;
}

#ifdef TEST

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* Check leap years */
    int length = 0;
    const char *pad = "";
    for (int i = 1895; i < 2105; i++)
    {
        if (is_leap_year(i))
        {
            int extra = printf("%s%d", pad, i);
            length += extra;
            if (length > 70)
            {
                putchar('\n');
                length = 0;
                pad = "";
            }
            else
                pad = ", ";
        }
    }
    if (length > 0)
        putchar('\n');

    /* Check conversions from YYYY-DDD to YYYY-MM-DD and back */
    const int years[] = { 1996, 1997 };
    enum { NUM_YEARS = sizeof(years) / sizeof(years[0]) };
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_YEARS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 366; j++)
        {
            int day;
            int mon;
            if (cvt_yd_to_ymd(years[i], j, &mon, &day) != 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to convert year %d, day %d to YYYY-MM-DD\n",
                        years[i], j);
            else
            {
                printf("Y = %4d, D = %3d --> M = %2d, D = %2d; ",
                       years[i], j, mon, day);
                int yday;
                if (cvt_ymd_to_yd(years[i], mon, day, &yday) != 0)
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to convert %4d-%.2d-%.2d to YYYY-DDD\n",
                            years[i], mon, day);
                else if (yday != j)
                    fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect day of year (%d wanted vs %d actual)\n",
                            j, yday);
                else
                    printf("Y = %4d, M = %.2d, D = %.2d --> D = %3d",
                           years[i], mon, day, yday);
                putchar('\n');
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

#endif
```

#### Partial output

```
1896, 1904, 1908, 1912, 1916, 1920, 1924, 1928, 1932, 1936, 1940, 1944, 1948
1952, 1956, 1960, 1964, 1968, 1972, 1976, 1980, 1984, 1988, 1992, 1996, 2000
2004, 2008, 2012, 2016, 2020, 2024, 2028, 2032, 2036, 2040, 2044, 2048, 2052
2056, 2060, 2064, 2068, 2072, 2076, 2080, 2084, 2088, 2092, 2096, 2104
Y = 1996, D =   1 --> M =  1, D =  1; Y = 1996, M = 01, D = 01 --> D =   1
Y = 1996, D =   2 --> M =  1, D =  2; Y = 1996, M = 01, D = 02 --> D =   2
Y = 1996, D =   3 --> M =  1, D =  3; Y = 1996, M = 01, D = 03 --> D =   3
...
Y = 1996, D =  27 --> M =  1, D = 27; Y = 1996, M = 01, D = 27 --> D =  27
Y = 1996, D =  28 --> M =  1, D = 28; Y = 1996, M = 01, D = 28 --> D =  28
Y = 1996, D =  29 --> M =  1, D = 29; Y = 1996, M = 01, D = 29 --> D =  29
Y = 1996, D =  30 --> M =  1, D = 30; Y = 1996, M = 01, D = 30 --> D =  30
Y = 1996, D =  31 --> M =  1, D = 31; Y = 1996, M = 01, D = 31 --> D =  31
Y = 1996, D =  32 --> M =  2, D =  1; Y = 1996, M = 02, D = 01 --> D =  32
Y = 1996, D =  33 --> M =  2, D =  2; Y = 1996, M = 02, D = 02 --> D =  33
Y = 1996, D =  34 --> M =  2, D =  3; Y = 1996, M = 02, D = 03 --> D =  34
...
Y = 1996, D =  58 --> M =  2, D = 27; Y = 1996, M = 02, D = 27 --> D =  58
Y = 1996, D =  59 --> M =  2, D = 28; Y = 1996, M = 02, D = 28 --> D =  59
Y = 1996, D =  60 --> M =  2, D = 29; Y = 1996, M = 02, D = 29 --> D =  60
Y = 1996, D =  61 --> M =  3, D =  1; Y = 1996, M = 03, D = 01 --> D =  61
Y = 1996, D =  62 --> M =  3, D =  2; Y = 1996, M = 03, D = 02 --> D =  62
Y = 1996, D =  63 --> M =  3, D =  3; Y = 1996, M = 03, D = 03 --> D =  63
...
Y = 1996, D =  87 --> M =  3, D = 27; Y = 1996, M = 03, D = 27 --> D =  87
Y = 1996, D =  88 --> M =  3, D = 28; Y = 1996, M = 03, D = 28 --> D =  88
Y = 1996, D =  89 --> M =  3, D = 29; Y = 1996, M = 03, D = 29 --> D =  89
Y = 1996, D =  90 --> M =  3, D = 30; Y = 1996, M = 03, D = 30 --> D =  90
Y = 1996, D =  91 --> M =  3, D = 31; Y = 1996, M = 03, D = 31 --> D =  91
Y = 1996, D =  92 --> M =  4, D =  1; Y = 1996, M = 04, D = 01 --> D =  92
Y = 1996, D =  93 --> M =  4, D =  2; Y = 1996, M = 04, D = 02 --> D =  93
Y = 1996, D =  94 --> M =  4, D =  3; Y = 1996, M = 04, D = 03 --> D =  94
...
Y = 1996, D = 118 --> M =  4, D = 27; Y = 1996, M = 04, D = 27 --> D = 118
Y = 1996, D = 119 --> M =  4, D = 28; Y = 1996, M = 04, D = 28 --> D = 119
Y = 1996, D = 120 --> M =  4, D = 29; Y = 1996, M = 04, D = 29 --> D = 120
Y = 1996, D = 121 --> M =  4, D = 30; Y = 1996, M = 04, D = 30 --> D = 121
Y = 1996, D = 122 --> M =  5, D =  1; Y = 1996, M = 05, D = 01 --> D = 122
Y = 1996, D = 123 --> M =  5, D =  2; Y = 1996, M = 05, D = 02 --> D = 123
Y = 1996, D = 124 --> M =  5, D =  3; Y = 1996, M = 05, D = 03 --> D = 124
...
Y = 1996, D = 148 --> M =  5, D = 27; Y = 1996, M = 05, D = 27 --> D = 148
Y = 1996, D = 149 --> M =  5, D = 28; Y = 1996, M = 05, D = 28 --> D = 149
Y = 1996, D = 150 --> M =  5, D = 29; Y = 1996, M = 05, D = 29 --> D = 150
Y = 1996, D = 151 --> M =  5, D = 30; Y = 1996, M = 05, D = 30 --> D = 151
Y = 1996, D = 152 --> M =  5, D = 31; Y = 1996, M = 05, D = 31 --> D = 152
Y = 1996, D = 153 --> M =  6, D =  1; Y = 1996, M = 06, D = 01 --> D = 153
Y = 1996, D = 154 --> M =  6, D =  2; Y = 1996, M = 06, D = 02 --> D = 154
Y = 1996, D = 155 --> M =  6, D =  3; Y = 1996, M = 06, D = 03 --> D = 155
...
Y = 1996, D = 179 --> M =  6, D = 27; Y = 1996, M = 06, D = 27 --> D = 179
Y = 1996, D = 180 --> M =  6, D = 28; Y = 1996, M = 06, D = 28 --> D = 180
Y = 1996, D = 181 --> M =  6, D = 29; Y = 1996, M = 06, D = 29 --> D = 181
Y = 1996, D = 182 --> M =  6, D = 30; Y = 1996, M = 06, D = 30 --> D = 182
Y = 1996, D = 183 --> M =  7, D =  1; Y = 1996, M = 07, D = 01 --> D = 183
Y = 1996, D = 184 --> M =  7, D =  2; Y = 1996, M = 07, D = 02 --> D = 184
Y = 1996, D = 185 --> M =  7, D =  3; Y = 1996, M = 07, D = 03 --> D = 185
...
Y = 1996, D = 209 --> M =  7, D = 27; Y = 1996, M = 07, D = 27 --> D = 209
Y = 1996, D = 210 --> M =  7, D = 28; Y = 1996, M = 07, D = 28 --> D = 210
Y = 1996, D = 211 --> M =  7, D = 29; Y = 1996, M = 07, D = 29 --> D = 211
Y = 1996, D = 212 --> M =  7, D = 30; Y = 1996, M = 07, D = 30 --> D = 212
Y = 1996, D = 213 --> M =  7, D = 31; Y = 1996, M = 07, D = 31 --> D = 213
Y = 1996, D = 214 --> M =  8, D =  1; Y = 1996, M = 08, D = 01 --> D = 214
Y = 1996, D = 215 --> M =  8, D =  2; Y = 1996, M = 08, D = 02 --> D = 215
Y = 1996, D = 216 --> M =  8, D =  3; Y = 1996, M = 08, D = 03 --> D = 216
...
Y = 1996, D = 240 --> M =  8, D = 27; Y = 1996, M = 08, D = 27 --> D = 240
Y = 1996, D = 241 --> M =  8, D = 28; Y = 1996, M = 08, D = 28 --> D = 241
Y = 1996, D = 242 --> M =  8, D = 29; Y = 1996, M = 08, D = 29 --> D = 242
Y = 1996, D = 243 --> M =  8, D = 30; Y = 1996, M = 08, D = 30 --> D = 243
Y = 1996, D = 244 --> M =  8, D = 31; Y = 1996, M = 08, D = 31 --> D = 244
Y = 1996, D = 245 --> M =  9, D =  1; Y = 1996, M = 09, D = 01 --> D = 245
Y = 1996, D = 246 --> M =  9, D =  2; Y = 1996, M = 09, D = 02 --> D = 246
Y = 1996, D = 247 --> M =  9, D =  3; Y = 1996, M = 09, D = 03 --> D = 247
...
Y = 1996, D = 271 --> M =  9, D = 27; Y = 1996, M = 09, D = 27 --> D = 271
Y = 1996, D = 272 --> M =  9, D = 28; Y = 1996, M = 09, D = 28 --> D = 272
Y = 1996, D = 273 --> M =  9, D = 29; Y = 1996, M = 09, D = 29 --> D = 273
Y = 1996, D = 274 --> M =  9, D = 30; Y = 1996, M = 09, D = 30 --> D = 274
Y = 1996, D = 275 --> M = 10, D =  1; Y = 1996, M = 10, D = 01 --> D = 275
Y = 1996, D = 276 --> M = 10, D =  2; Y = 1996, M = 10, D = 02 --> D = 276
Y = 1996, D = 277 --> M = 10, D =  3; Y = 1996, M = 10, D = 03 --> D = 277
...
Y = 1996, D = 301 --> M = 10, D = 27; Y = 1996, M = 10, D = 27 --> D = 301
Y = 1996, D = 302 --> M = 10, D = 28; Y = 1996, M = 10, D = 28 --> D = 302
Y = 1996, D = 303 --> M = 10, D = 29; Y = 1996, M = 10, D = 29 --> D = 303
Y = 1996, D = 304 --> M = 10, D = 30; Y = 1996, M = 10, D = 30 --> D = 304
Y = 1996, D = 305 --> M = 10, D = 31; Y = 1996, M = 10, D = 31 --> D = 305
Y = 1996, D = 306 --> M = 11, D =  1; Y = 1996, M = 11, D = 01 --> D = 306
Y = 1996, D = 307 --> M = 11, D =  2; Y = 1996, M = 11, D = 02 --> D = 307
Y = 1996, D = 308 --> M = 11, D =  3; Y = 1996, M = 11, D = 03 --> D = 308
...
Y = 1996, D = 332 --> M = 11, D = 27; Y = 1996, M = 11, D = 27 --> D = 332
Y = 1996, D = 333 --> M = 11, D = 28; Y = 1996, M = 11, D = 28 --> D = 333
Y = 1996, D = 334 --> M = 11, D = 29; Y = 1996, M = 11, D = 29 --> D = 334
Y = 1996, D = 335 --> M = 11, D = 30; Y = 1996, M = 11, D = 30 --> D = 335
Y = 1996, D = 336 --> M = 12, D =  1; Y = 1996, M = 12, D = 01 --> D = 336
Y = 1996, D = 337 --> M = 12, D =  2; Y = 1996, M = 12, D = 02 --> D = 337
Y = 1996, D = 338 --> M = 12, D =  3; Y = 1996, M = 12, D = 03 --> D = 338
...
Y = 1996, D = 362 --> M = 12, D = 27; Y = 1996, M = 12, D = 27 --> D = 362
Y = 1996, D = 363 --> M = 12, D = 28; Y = 1996, M = 12, D = 28 --> D = 363
Y = 1996, D = 364 --> M = 12, D = 29; Y = 1996, M = 12, D = 29 --> D = 364
Y = 1996, D = 365 --> M = 12, D = 30; Y = 1996, M = 12, D = 30 --> D = 365
Y = 1996, D = 366 --> M = 12, D = 31; Y = 1996, M = 12, D = 31 --> D = 366
Y = 1997, D =   1 --> M =  1, D =  1; Y = 1997, M = 01, D = 01 --> D =   1
Y = 1997, D =   2 --> M =  1, D =  2; Y = 1997, M = 01, D = 02 --> D =   2
Y = 1997, D =   3 --> M =  1, D =  3; Y = 1997, M = 01, D = 03 --> D =   3
...
Y = 1997, D =  27 --> M =  1, D = 27; Y = 1997, M = 01, D = 27 --> D =  27
Y = 1997, D =  28 --> M =  1, D = 28; Y = 1997, M = 01, D = 28 --> D =  28
Y = 1997, D =  29 --> M =  1, D = 29; Y = 1997, M = 01, D = 29 --> D =  29
Y = 1997, D =  30 --> M =  1, D = 30; Y = 1997, M = 01, D = 30 --> D =  30
Y = 1997, D =  31 --> M =  1, D = 31; Y = 1997, M = 01, D = 31 --> D =  31
Y = 1997, D =  32 --> M =  2, D =  1; Y = 1997, M = 02, D = 01 --> D =  32
Y = 1997, D =  33 --> M =  2, D =  2; Y = 1997, M = 02, D = 02 --> D =  33
Y = 1997, D =  34 --> M =  2, D =  3; Y = 1997, M = 02, D = 03 --> D =  34
...
Y = 1997, D =  58 --> M =  2, D = 27; Y = 1997, M = 02, D = 27 --> D =  58
Y = 1997, D =  59 --> M =  2, D = 28; Y = 1997, M = 02, D = 28 --> D =  59
Y = 1997, D =  60 --> M =  3, D =  1; Y = 1997, M = 03, D = 01 --> D =  60
Y = 1997, D =  61 --> M =  3, D =  2; Y = 1997, M = 03, D = 02 --> D =  61
Y = 1997, D =  62 --> M =  3, D =  3; Y = 1997, M = 03, D = 03 --> D =  62
...
Y = 1997, D =  86 --> M =  3, D = 27; Y = 1997, M = 03, D = 27 --> D =  86
Y = 1997, D =  87 --> M =  3, D = 28; Y = 1997, M = 03, D = 28 --> D =  87
Y = 1997, D =  88 --> M =  3, D = 29; Y = 1997, M = 03, D = 29 --> D =  88
Y = 1997, D =  89 --> M =  3, D = 30; Y = 1997, M = 03, D = 30 --> D =  89
Y = 1997, D =  90 --> M =  3, D = 31; Y = 1997, M = 03, D = 31 --> D =  90
Y = 1997, D =  91 --> M =  4, D =  1; Y = 1997, M = 04, D = 01 --> D =  91
Y = 1997, D =  92 --> M =  4, D =  2; Y = 1997, M = 04, D = 02 --> D =  92
Y = 1997, D =  93 --> M =  4, D =  3; Y = 1997, M = 04, D = 03 --> D =  93
...
Y = 1997, D = 117 --> M =  4, D = 27; Y = 1997, M = 04, D = 27 --> D = 117
Y = 1997, D = 118 --> M =  4, D = 28; Y = 1997, M = 04, D = 28 --> D = 118
Y = 1997, D = 119 --> M =  4, D = 29; Y = 1997, M = 04, D = 29 --> D = 119
Y = 1997, D = 120 --> M =  4, D = 30; Y = 1997, M = 04, D = 30 --> D = 120
Y = 1997, D = 121 --> M =  5, D =  1; Y = 1997, M = 05, D = 01 --> D = 121
Y = 1997, D = 122 --> M =  5, D =  2; Y = 1997, M = 05, D = 02 --> D = 122
Y = 1997, D = 123 --> M =  5, D =  3; Y = 1997, M = 05, D = 03 --> D = 123
...
Y = 1997, D = 147 --> M =  5, D = 27; Y = 1997, M = 05, D = 27 --> D = 147
Y = 1997, D = 148 --> M =  5, D = 28; Y = 1997, M = 05, D = 28 --> D = 148
Y = 1997, D = 149 --> M =  5, D = 29; Y = 1997, M = 05, D = 29 --> D = 149
Y = 1997, D = 150 --> M =  5, D = 30; Y = 1997, M = 05, D = 30 --> D = 150
Y = 1997, D = 151 --> M =  5, D = 31; Y = 1997, M = 05, D = 31 --> D = 151
Y = 1997, D = 152 --> M =  6, D =  1; Y = 1997, M = 06, D = 01 --> D = 152
Y = 1997, D = 153 --> M =  6, D =  2; Y = 1997, M = 06, D = 02 --> D = 153
Y = 1997, D = 154 --> M =  6, D =  3; Y = 1997, M = 06, D = 03 --> D = 154
...
Y = 1997, D = 178 --> M =  6, D = 27; Y = 1997, M = 06, D = 27 --> D = 178
Y = 1997, D = 179 --> M =  6, D = 28; Y = 1997, M = 06, D = 28 --> D = 179
Y = 1997, D = 180 --> M =  6, D = 29; Y = 1997, M = 06, D = 29 --> D = 180
Y = 1997, D = 181 --> M =  6, D = 30; Y = 1997, M = 06, D = 30 --> D = 181
Y = 1997, D = 182 --> M =  7, D =  1; Y = 1997, M = 07, D = 01 --> D = 182
Y = 1997, D = 183 --> M =  7, D =  2; Y = 1997, M = 07, D = 02 --> D = 183
Y = 1997, D = 184 --> M =  7, D =  3; Y = 1997, M = 07, D = 03 --> D = 184
...
Y = 1997, D = 208 --> M =  7, D = 27; Y = 1997, M = 07, D = 27 --> D = 208
Y = 1997, D = 209 --> M =  7, D = 28; Y = 1997, M = 07, D = 28 --> D = 209
Y = 1997, D = 210 --> M =  7, D = 29; Y = 1997, M = 07, D = 29 --> D = 210
Y = 1997, D = 211 --> M =  7, D = 30; Y = 1997, M = 07, D = 30 --> D = 211
Y = 1997, D = 212 --> M =  7, D = 31; Y = 1997, M = 07, D = 31 --> D = 212
Y = 1997, D = 213 --> M =  8, D =  1; Y = 1997, M = 08, D = 01 --> D = 213
Y = 1997, D = 214 --> M =  8, D =  2; Y = 1997, M = 08, D = 02 --> D = 214
Y = 1997, D = 215 --> M =  8, D =  3; Y = 1997, M = 08, D = 03 --> D = 215
...
Y = 1997, D = 239 --> M =  8, D = 27; Y = 1997, M = 08, D = 27 --> D = 239
Y = 1997, D = 240 --> M =  8, D = 28; Y = 1997, M = 08, D = 28 --> D = 240
Y = 1997, D = 241 --> M =  8, D = 29; Y = 1997, M = 08, D = 29 --> D = 241
Y = 1997, D = 242 --> M =  8, D = 30; Y = 1997, M = 08, D = 30 --> D = 242
Y = 1997, D = 243 --> M =  8, D = 31; Y = 1997, M = 08, D = 31 --> D = 243
Y = 1997, D = 244 --> M =  9, D =  1; Y = 1997, M = 09, D = 01 --> D = 244
Y = 1997, D = 245 --> M =  9, D =  2; Y = 1997, M = 09, D = 02 --> D = 245
Y = 1997, D = 246 --> M =  9, D =  3; Y = 1997, M = 09, D = 03 --> D = 246
...
Y = 1997, D = 270 --> M =  9, D = 27; Y = 1997, M = 09, D = 27 --> D = 270
Y = 1997, D = 271 --> M =  9, D = 28; Y = 1997, M = 09, D = 28 --> D = 271
Y = 1997, D = 272 --> M =  9, D = 29; Y = 1997, M = 09, D = 29 --> D = 272
Y = 1997, D = 273 --> M =  9, D = 30; Y = 1997, M = 09, D = 30 --> D = 273
Y = 1997, D = 274 --> M = 10, D =  1; Y = 1997, M = 10, D = 01 --> D = 274
Y = 1997, D = 275 --> M = 10, D =  2; Y = 1997, M = 10, D = 02 --> D = 275
Y = 1997, D = 276 --> M = 10, D =  3; Y = 1997, M = 10, D = 03 --> D = 276
...
Y = 1997, D = 300 --> M = 10, D = 27; Y = 1997, M = 10, D = 27 --> D = 300
Y = 1997, D = 301 --> M = 10, D = 28; Y = 1997, M = 10, D = 28 --> D = 301
Y = 1997, D = 302 --> M = 10, D = 29; Y = 1997, M = 10, D = 29 --> D = 302
Y = 1997, D = 303 --> M = 10, D = 30; Y = 1997, M = 10, D = 30 --> D = 303
Y = 1997, D = 304 --> M = 10, D = 31; Y = 1997, M = 10, D = 31 --> D = 304
Y = 1997, D = 305 --> M = 11, D =  1; Y = 1997, M = 11, D = 01 --> D = 305
Y = 1997, D = 306 --> M = 11, D =  2; Y = 1997, M = 11, D = 02 --> D = 306
Y = 1997, D = 307 --> M = 11, D =  3; Y = 1997, M = 11, D = 03 --> D = 307
...
Y = 1997, D = 331 --> M = 11, D = 27; Y = 1997, M = 11, D = 27 --> D = 331
Y = 1997, D = 332 --> M = 11, D = 28; Y = 1997, M = 11, D = 28 --> D = 332
Y = 1997, D = 333 --> M = 11, D = 29; Y = 1997, M = 11, D = 29 --> D = 333
Y = 1997, D = 334 --> M = 11, D = 30; Y = 1997, M = 11, D = 30 --> D = 334
Y = 1997, D = 335 --> M = 12, D =  1; Y = 1997, M = 12, D = 01 --> D = 335
Y = 1997, D = 336 --> M = 12, D =  2; Y = 1997, M = 12, D = 02 --> D = 336
Y = 1997, D = 337 --> M = 12, D =  3; Y = 1997, M = 12, D = 03 --> D = 337
...
Y = 1997, D = 361 --> M = 12, D = 27; Y = 1997, M = 12, D = 27 --> D = 361
Y = 1997, D = 362 --> M = 12, D = 28; Y = 1997, M = 12, D = 28 --> D = 362
Y = 1997, D = 363 --> M = 12, D = 29; Y = 1997, M = 12, D = 29 --> D = 363
Y = 1997, D = 364 --> M = 12, D = 30; Y = 1997, M = 12, D = 30 --> D = 364
Y = 1997, D = 365 --> M = 12, D = 31; Y = 1997, M = 12, D = 31 --> D = 365
Failed to convert year 1997, day 366 to YYYY-MM-DD
```

Comment: =O Never ever roll your own date functions. There are far more exceptions to consider than you will get to know in reasonable time. Always use standard library functions! (Best source of reasoning: all articles at [The Daily WTF](https://thedailywtf.com/) about dates.)

Comment: It depends on which idiosyncrasies of the calendars you want to take into account. There isn't a standard function that does the day-of-year to month-day conversion; therefore, you have to either write your own or find an off-site resource, and off-site resources are off-topic for SO. If you want to deal with the switches between Julian and Gregorian calendars, then you need much more data (about the dates when the switch occurred) to control the mapping. This applies the so-called "proleptic Gregorian calendar". If that's not what you want, don't use it. That is sufficient for many purposes.

Comment: The nearest approximation to a standard function is `mktime()`.  Since it 'normalizes' the elements of the `struct tm` is is given, I suppose you could claim that the given day of the year (for sake of argument, 300), was the 300th day of January, and then look that the `tm_mon`, `tm_day` and `tm_yday` values set by `mktime()` (the `tm_yday` to check that it did what you expected).  It's pretty obscure way of thinking about it though.  Also, someone has to write the library functions — it can be done.

Comment: Right, someone wrote those functions. But I'm sure that she spent a lot of time and her code was reviewed and corrected multiple times. All this happens since many years. I would not dare to write my own function. ;-) And the problem can not be new. If I had the task of the OP, I would rather spend several hours of research instead of writing code.

Comment: And what makes you think I'm not one of those people who's spent years writing date functions?  Anyway, I've added Option 1 using `mktime()`.  Working with `struct tm` and `mktime()` is its own version of fraught; there are plenty of ways of getting it wrong (`tm_year`, `tm_mon`, `tm_yday` have _interesting_ mappings, shall we say).

Comment: You must be confined at home with no alternative to SO :)

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes: Confined at home — yes.  No alternative — not quite; there's always work and the merge from hell, prior to making a second merge from hell in one codeline, and then merging that into the other codeline (yup; you guessed it; another merge from hell!).  (And yes, I think I prefer the older yellow block quotes too.)

Comment: The CM system is Atria ClearCase.  I use `ct findmerge` in various guises.

Comment: Sounds like a splitting (and merging) headache.

Comment: 20 years accumulated technical debt — and some weirdnesses in the grammar that requires one specific variant of Yacc, and … It is 'entertaining', in a gritted teeth sort of way.

Comment: Condoleances... Is the project open source?

Comment: No; I doubt if any open source project uses Atria — it is the antithesis of "free".  Very clever in many ways; but not free.