# Bash : Shell Script : Find out if the current (Julian) day is the last day of the month

Tags: bash

I have a requirement where I need to kick off certain processes on end of every month. I am getting the date as an Input from previous process and date is in Julian format (for e.g. 2020105 CCYYDDD). I need to check if the date passed is month end. I'm thinking of 2 options:

1. Directly check if Julian date is month end date.
2. Convert Julian date to Gregorian or Regular date and then check if it is month end.

In either cases, please guide me to some materials I can refer.

I'm aware I can get the current date using `echo $(date '+%Y-%m-%d')` and then check if its the last day of the month. But I need to strongly consider the Julian date that is coming as the input to my process as it is being sent by the Business.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: One way to find out if YYYY-DDD is the end of a month is to check whether YYYY-(DDD+1) is the first of the month (which does mean converting to a regular date).  You might find some help at [Given a day of a year, how would I convert it into date/month format?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60769352/15168), but it is a C question with one answer showing two different ways of doing the calculation in C.  You'd have to package some variation on the code as a program.  Beware end-of-year and off-by-one.  There probably are ways to do it in Bash with GNU `date`; they're probably fairly obscure.

Comment: ISO 8601 (§4.1.3) calls the YYYYDDD format an 'ordinal date'.  You may find that helpful in searching; I've not tried (yet).

Comment: Thank you. Let me try searching with that

Answer (score 1):

If you have Gnu date, you can use the following function:

```
next_day_of_month () { 
    date -d "${1:0:4}-01-01 $((10#${1:4:3})) days" +%-d
}
```

which takes a Julian date in the format you specify, and computes the day of the month of the following day.

If you want a pure bash solution (which, despite the fact that it calls no external utilities, is seriously slow), you can use the following.

There is a not-very-complicated formula which can be used to compute the month corresponding to the day number, but it requires the count of days starting with the previous March 1, rather than with January 1. Correcting the day number in that way requires knowing whether the year is a leap year or not, which makes things just a tad more complicated.

Anyway, here it is. [Note 1]

```
# Compute the month number (1-12) corresponding to a day in
# in "Julian" format YYYYJJJ (001 == Jan. 1; 365/6 == Dec. 31)
# Yes, I know it's full of magic numbers.
month_for_julian_day () { 
    local -i y=${1:0:4} j=10#${1:4:3} march1=60
    if (( y % 400 == 0 )) || ! (( y % 100 == 0 )) && (( y % 4 == 0)); then
        march1=61
    fi
    if (( j >= march1 )); then j=j-march1; else j=j+305; fi
    local -i m=(j*5+461)/153
    if (( m > 12 )); then m=m-12; fi
    echo $m
}
```

To make use of this, it would be handy to have

```
# Advance a Julian date to the next day.
# Note: this one doesn't wrap around. Because of the way it's used
# here, that doesn't matter.
julian_next() { printf "%s%03d" ${1:0:4} $((10#${1:4:3})); }
```

Then you can define

```
# Succeeds if the Julian date is the last day of a month
is_last_day_of_month() {
    (( $(month_for_julian_day $j) != $(month_for_julian_day $(next_julian $j)) ))
}
```

---

#### Notes:

1. After I pasted this, I noticed that the syntax highlighter being used here thinks that `#` starts a comment. That's not true. `#` only starts a comment if it's the first character in a word. In this case, the assignment `j=10#${1:4:3}` forces the last three digits of the supplied date to be interpreted in base 10.

Comment: Hi rici, Thanks for the solution, I'm new to bash and I'm getting below error
`month_for_julian_day () {
> local -i y=${1:0:4} j=10#${1:4:3} march1=60
> if (( y % 400 == 0 )) || ! (( y % 100 == 0 )) && (( y % 4 == 0)); then
>     march1=61
> fi
> if (( j >= march1 )); then j=j-march1; else j=j+305; fi
> local -i m=(j*5+461)/153
> if (( m > 12 )); then m=m-12 fi
> echo $m
> }
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'`

Comment: @Prashy: Sorry. That was apparently a copy-and-paste error. The `fi` at the third last line was originally on a line by itself; where it is in the paste, it needs a semicolon before it. I added the semicolon, and tested that it works. Apologies again.

Comment: @Prashy: if you're new to bash, it might not be immediately obvious: the intention of all that is to be able to write `if is_last_day_of_month $julian; then kick_off_the_process: fi`. Of course, you can use shorter function names if you prefer :-)